# GETBULK requests returns OIDs other than specified one

Tags: java, snmp, snmp4j

I'm using snmp4j to get a auto increment `OID`. The main `OID` looks like `1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.12.1` and auto increment number is appended to it:

```
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.12.1.158271
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.12.1.158272
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.12.1.158273
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.12.1.158274
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.12.1.158275
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.12.1.158276
```

First of all if we want to get the `OID` with maximum number the correct way is to use `GETBULK` method. Am I right? When I send a `GETBULK` request like below, the result is weird:

```
PDU p = new PDU();
p.add(new VariableBinding(new OID("1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.12.1")));
p.setType(PDU.GETBULK);
p.setMaxRepetitions(200);

ResponseEvent re = snmp.send(p, target);
for (VariableBinding v : re.getResponse().getVariableBindings()) {
    System.out.println(v);
}
```

Here is the result:

```
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.12.1.158273 = 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.12.1.158274 = 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.12.1.158275 = 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.12.1.158276 = 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.12.1.158277 = 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.12.1.158278 = 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.12.1.158279 = 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.12.1.158280 = 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.12.1.158281 = 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.12.2.158273 = 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.12.2.158274 = 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.12.2.158275 = 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.12.2.158276 = 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.12.2.158277 = 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.12.2.158278 = 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.12.2.158279 = 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.12.2.158280 = 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.12.2.158281 = 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.13.1.158273 = 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.13.1.158274 = 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.13.1.158275 = 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.13.1.158276 = 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.13.1.158277 = 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.13.1.158278 = 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.13.1.158279 = 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.13.1.158280 = 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.13.1.158287 = 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.13.2.158273 = 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.13.2.158274 = 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.13.2.158275 = 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.13.2.158276 = 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.13.2.158277 = 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.13.2.158278 = 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.13.2.158279 = 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.13.2.158280 = 0
```

The problem is it contains other `OID`s such `1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.13.2` as well. Am I doing something wrong? Isn't there any robust and efficient mechanism to do this? I'm doing this for large number of network switches and the response contains many `VariableBinding`s which I don't use.

Comment: Could you please specify the MIB definition for the specific columnar OID?

Comment: @MJSG How should I get MIB definition? I mean which application I should use to do get information? I'm using a simple MIB viewer which I think it doesn't show much information.

Answer (score 0):

One way to look at this is like telling the device to perform 'N' get-next operations on the provided OID and return the results.

In this scenario, when the device reaches the last row for that particular column, it moves to the next column in that table (or the next OID after the table if we are on the last column).

In short, the answer is that you are not doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The GETBULK operation has the same effect of executing many times of GETNEXT.
And GETNEXT means it will always try to get the next  in the ***lexicographical*** ordering of the known object names.that's to say it will return 
1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.12.1 's **successors** ( taking the whole MIB as a tree.) until it didn't get any succssors.
For your question:
Try the following codes:

```
       for (VariableBinding v : re.getResponse().getVariableBindings())  {
            if (!v.getOid().startsWith(startOID))
            {
                // the startOID = new OID("1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.6.3.1.12.1");
                //end here, sub tree ends.

                break;
            }
        }
```